# CSS - Two stylesheets rendering one after other (Opencart)

Tags: html, css, opencart

I am having an issue here that is driving me crazy. 
On my website, it seems to be loading and rendering one CSS file, then loading the CSS overrides I have created in `luke.css` afterwards to eventually alter the website to how I want it. If you navigate to [MY WEBSITE HERE](http://ssuk.li/store), you will see that a cream colour loads first on the left sidebar, then afterwards is overwritten by my styles.

I have never had this issue before! I created the 'child' stylesheet so that the theme installed on the OpenCart system is easily upgradable rather than editing core files.

I have the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncnx8g2k/)** of a snippet of the `header.tpl` file here to see if anyone can see anything causing the issue.

My first thought was that it was because there were two stylesheets one after the other - So I merged the two stylesheets together [no solution]

Secondly, I thought it may be because of the order of the css files in the header - So I moved them next to each other with `luke.css` last [no solution]

I have a LESS compiler on the OC dashboard but in all honestly, I am not entirely sure how to use this or its benefits from what code I already have. If you recommend compiling with a pre-processor let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a stylesheet at the bottom of the page, right before the `</body>`. This stylesheet sets the background color of your page to white.

What is happening is that the browser has to load lots of JavaScript before it reaches the end of the body. It renders the entire page briefly; only to find that it needs to change the background color.

Move this stylesheet (in fact, move all of the stylesheets) inside the `<head>` section before any scripts.

Comment: Mate, you are a legend! Thank you. I actually cannot believe I missed that stylesheet - I guess looking through pages of code gives you slight tunnel vision.

I know this theme is too heavy. Some vQmod is responsible but I am working on shrinking this down or removing scripts of stylesheets on pages where they are not needed. In terms of the heavy issue, in your opinion would consolidating these files together and minifying help? I am looking on pingdom, even the htaccess redirect changing root domain to the subdomain for the store is killing 2 seconds. Any recommendations?

Comment: Analyze your website using Google PageSpeed Insights for suggestions (but yes, it _will_ tell you to combine, minify and gzip stylesheet and JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

You have javascripts between your theme.css and editor_settings.css files.
Javascript loading is blocking.

Reordering your assets should solve your problem.

Comment: This was a very helpful comment. Thank you. I have reordered and moved the JS after of the </head> tag?